# Running process during different power states

Tags: linux, power-management

I am beginner to PM.
Is it possible to execute a process under different power states? If yes, how should I proceed with it?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by `power states`?

Comment: @jsotola Power management states as Powered on, suspend to ram, power off.

Comment: you can do think during transition of state not during state